# One 'Posts' resource with two different routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, url-routing

I'd like to get all the restful routes for two (or more) different routes using one 'posts' controller. I'm working on a multibrand site and I'm trying to keep down the duplicate code.

```
brand1/blog/:id
brand2/blog/:id
```

Right now I have:

```
resources :posts, :path => "brand1/blog"
     get 'brand2/blog' => 'posts#brand2_index'
```

I can get the two blogs to display properly using a @post.brand parameter but the individual post urls end up always being for brand1.

I'm very new to rails and programming in general so I could definitely be missing something fundamental.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would typically be covered with [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :brands, path: "", only: [] do
   resources :posts, path: "blog", only: [:index, :show] #-> url.com/:brand_id/blog/:id
end
```

Since you're not using `brands` as a resource, you'll want to use a [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) (negates the need for a controller):

```
#config/routes.rb
scope :brand do
   resources :posts, path: "blog", only: [:index, :show] #-> url.com/:brand/blog/:id
end
```

You'll then be able to pick up the `:brand` in your params:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def show
     @brand = Brand.find params[:brand]
     @post  = @brand.posts.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

--

If you wanted to make sure that only valid brands were accepted as routes, you'll want to use a custom constraint:

```
#config/routes.rb
scope :brand, constraints: BrandExists do
    resources :posts, path: "blog", only: [:index, :show] #-> url.com/:brand/blog/:id
end

#lib/brand_exists.rb
module BrandExists

    def initializer(router)
        @router = router
    end

    def self.matches?(request)
        Brand.exists? request.path.split("/").first
    end

end
```

[Very good ref here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-constraints).

Comment: This got me there. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

A clean way to handle this is using scopes. You would define your routes like this:

```
scope ':brand_name' do
  resources :posts, path: 'blog'
end
```

There is no need to duplicate controller actions. In your controller you will get the brand with `params[:brand_name]`. The generated routes will be as follows:

```
    posts GET        /:brand_name/blog(.:format)                     posts#index
          POST       /:brand_name/blog(.:format)                     posts#create
 new_post GET        /:brand_name/blog/new(.:format)                 posts#new
edit_post GET        /:brand_name/blog/:id/edit(.:format)            posts#edit
     post GET        /:brand_name/blog/:id(.:format)                 posts#show
          PATCH      /:brand_name/blog/:id(.:format)                 posts#update
          PUT        /:brand_name/blog/:id(.:format)                 posts#update
          DELETE     /:brand_name/blog/:id(.:format)                 posts#destroy
     page GET        /pages/*id                                      high_voltage/pages#show
```

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting your resources as below and then run `rake routes` to see what you're provided with.

```
resources :posts do
    get 'brand1/blog', to: "posts#brand1_index"
    get 'brand2/blog', to: "posts#brand2_index"
end
```

Justin